# LF411 behavior at -15V

Tags: operational-amplifier, saturation

I'm doing the following exercise from the Hayes' "Learning the Art of Electronics"

[image]

The circuit behaves as following:

1. When the pot's output is positive, the opamp's output is saturated at about +14.8V
2. When the pot's output is negative but NOT close to -15V, the opamp's output is saturated at about -14V
3. When the pot's output is negative AND close to -15V, the opamp's output jumps back to the positive saturation at about +14.8V

The items 1 and 2 in the list are perfectly expected. But the item 3 is very suprising. I looked into the datasheet but didn't find
a mentioning of such a behavior. Is LF411 actually supposed to behave like this? Or is something wrong with the instances I acquired?

Comment: maybe the pot is defective ... what do you observe when the opamp's input is disconnected from the pot?

Comment: **common mode input range** only extends down to -11.5 V with a -15V supply.  So the bottom-end of your pot is "too far". Manufacturers don't like to admit that their opamps have this characteristic that you've found, but many opamps do the same. Some don't, and manufacturers brag about this "feature". Search for **opamp phase reversal**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've encountered [phase reversal](https://www.analog.com/media/en/training-seminars/tutorials/MT-036.pdf) which is often associated with JFET and BJT amplifiers and involves a malfunction of the input stage. This was encountered because you exceeded this datasheet spec (given with a +/- 15 V supply, extraneous columns removed from screenshot):

[image]

Let's look at the op amp schematic where I marked the currents in the differential input pair:

[image]

Normally, the tail current \$I_{tail}\$ splits, with equal portions being sent down the left and right branches. When the input on the (+) input (right) is less than that on the (-) input (left), J2 conducts more current, pulling the base of Q4 up. Q4 buffers this increasing voltage to Q5's base. Q5, acting as a common emitter amplifier, performs inverting amplification, causing the voltage on Q8 and Q9 bases to decrease. Q8/Q9 form a push-pull pair of common-collectors, and cause the output voltage to decrease toward the positive rail.

When you encounter phase reversal, it is likely the case that J2's junction stops being reverse biased and becomes forward-biased as Vin falls:

[image]

Essentially, J1/J2 have stopped acting as a differential pair, and J2 is simply acting as a forward-biased diode.

This causes the tail current (created by Q13/Q14) to all go via the right branch, while also pulling *down* Q4's gate directly through the forward-biased junction of the J2 JFET. Since Q4's gate voltage is dropping, Q5's gate also drops abruptly, causing the bases of Q8/9 to increase abruptly to the positive rail. This explains why the output suddenly jumps to a high voltage - The relationship J1 gate -> Q4 gate goes from inverting to non-inverting.

If you connect a precise ammeter in series with the input from the pot, you may be able to observe that the op amp begins to conduct significant current via the input pin. This is a hallmark sign of malfunction, since a properly-biased JFET op amp should have essentially no DC current via its input pins.

Comment: Thank you very much for such a detailed explanation!